# Getting UTF-8 URL parameter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I am trying to get a text input field whose value gets sent as the parameter for an XSL transformation which is performed in JavaScript. I have set up a form with the get method, and my script gets the URL parameter like this:

```
var word=unescape((''+self.location.search).substring(5)).toLowerCase();
```

This works fine, except when the input contains special characters. I have set the HTML page's encoding to UTF-8, and I have added

```
accept-charset="utf-8"
```

to the form. I have also specified charset="utf-8" in the script tag, but it still doesn't work. My browser (Firefox) is set to UTF-8 as the default encoding. I have tried removing the unescape function too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
decodeURIComponent()
```

instead of

```
unescape
```

see @ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: See http://w3fools.com/ then see [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)